# LINQ Query - Where has child items

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework with a relational SQL Database. For example sake, lets say i've got two tables:

```
Customers
Invoices
```

Customers are a one to many relationship with Invoices, however not every customer has an invoice.

I'd like to do a query that will get any Customers that have at least one invoice. Like:

```
Dim queryCustomersWithInvoices = From rows in context.customers
                                 Where rows.has(Invoices)
```

The `Where` statement is the problem, the syntax is wrong, it's just expressing my intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an Invoices property on the customer ...

```
Where rows.Invoices.Any()
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. use .Any(), the linq version of 'where exists'. Explained here: [Exists query with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261840/exists-query-with-linq)
2. write something like `where rows.Invoices.Count > 0`

The first solution is probably faster as I suppose it doesn't need to actually count the invoices.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to count the invoices if it is a property of the customer.

```
Dim queryCustomersWithInvoices = From rows in context.customers
                             Where rows.Invoices.Count() >=1
```